# Storing and editing a list of list in a function

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a tic tac toe game.  One of the requirements is I need to have a list of lists with 0s for unoccupied spaces and a  1s for occupied spaces.  my thought process is to take my user input and send it to my grid_test function to check if the space is taken.  I'm running into a problem that when I reenter the function it resets my list to all 0s.  Is there a way to make my list hold it's value for each turn or should I look into doing this outside of a function?

```
def grid_test(xcord, ycord):
    grid_tester = [[0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0]]

    print(grid_tester)  #shows the array before anything is changed
    if grid_tester[xcord][ycord] == 1:
        print("Space is already taken.  Please select a different space:")
        print(grid_tester)
        return False
    elif grid_tester[xcord][ycord] == 0:
        grid_tester[xcord][ycord] = 1
        print(grid_tester)  #shows the array after
        return True

def play_game():
    turn = 1
    grid_values = [[" ", " ", " "],
                    [" ", " ", " "],
                    [" ", " ", " "]]
    while turn < 9:
        print("turn = ", turn)  #turn counter.  here just for testing.
        print("X's Turn")

        # ASK user to select a row              FOR X
        xrow = int(input("pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
        xrow += - 1
        while xrow < 0 or xrow >= 3:
            if xrow not in range(0 - 3):
                print("Invalid option!!!")
                xrow = int(input("pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
                xrow += - 1

        # ASk user to select a column               FOR X
        xcolumn = int(input("pick a column (1, 2, 3): "))
        xcolumn += - 1
        while xcolumn < 0 or xcolumn >= 3:
            if xcolumn not in range(0 - 3):
                print("Invalid option!!!")
                xcolumn = int(input("pick a column (1, 2, 3): "))
                xcolumn += - 1

        test = grid_test(xrow, xcolumn)
        print(test)

        grid_values[xrow][xcolumn] = "X"
        turn += 1

        print("+---+---+---+")
        print("|", grid_values[0][0], "|", grid_values[0][1], "|", grid_values[0][2], "|")
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print("|", grid_values[1][0], "|", grid_values[1][1], "|", grid_values[1][2], "|")
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print("|", grid_values[2][0], "|", grid_values[2][1], "|", grid_values[2][2], "|")
        print("+---+---+---+")
        print()
```

Comment: If you want `grid_tester` to retain its values, you'd need to create it outside of the function.  Everytime you call the function, that first `grid_tester = [[0, 0, 0],...` line will run and create a new 2D list of 0s.

Comment: Alright, so I should just scrap the whole function and just use the code within my play_game function?

Comment: I would just pass the 2D list in as another argument. If a function needs external data, pass it in.

Comment: No, you should create your game grid outside the function and pass it into the function as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is every time you call `grid_test` it's assigning `grid_tester` the value of `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`. I would recommend moving that line out of the function, then have `grid_tester` be passed into the function as a parameter.